# .htacces is being ignored in wp-admin folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to add protection to my wordpress site by specifing what ip addresses can access the admin dashboard. I've created a .htaccess file in /wp-admin folder and added the code. However it seems that the .htaccess file is being completely ignored. Does anybody know why this is happening.

Code:

```
  order deny,allow
  allow from 000.000.000.000 (my ip address)
  deny from all
```

Comment: `allow from 000.000.000.000 /` is the `/` a typo? Is the `.htaccess` on the root folder or inside the `/wp-admin` folder?

Comment: No, that was a mistake when copying. It's not in my original file. The .htaccess is inside the /wp-admin folder.

Comment: And how do you know its being ignored? have you tried changing 000.000.000.000 to some other IP not yours to see if you can access that folder?

Comment: Also keep in mind that this will not prevent people from accessing the `wp-login.php` as the login page is not inside the `wp-admin` folder so you will need a different protection for it.

Comment: Yes, I've tried changing the IP and it allows me access. I understand that will allow users to access wp-login.php, but it still should not allow them to access the wp admin area, right?

Comment: it should not allow them to access anything within `wp-admin` folder yes and if that is not working for you I am afraid `.htaccess` may be disabled.

Comment: Yeah, I just came to the same conclusion. :) I need to get that enabled. I'll update once I've got it working or not working.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to create a new .htaccess file in your text editor and upload to your `wp-admin` folder.

For more details please refer the link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks#Limit_Access_to_wp-admin_by_IP

Copy code

```
order deny,allow
allow from 202.090.21.1 (replace with your IP address)
deny from all
```